# Datagram Socket of Opne JDK 7 is not throwing bind exception

Tags: java, sockets

I use Communication interface to perform SNMP related operation. In
SNMPV1CommuncationInterface uses DatagramSocket to bind to UDP port
thats 162. If its bound by other process, this was giving
SocketException. This behavior was with Java 6

But recently after migrating to Open JDK 7, i am not
getting Socket Exception.

I am running tool called net_SNMP to bind the port 162.

Same works with JDK 6 but not with Open JDK 7.

I used Socket,ServerSocket as well to check if port is bind but none
is giving any error.

If use netstat -nao, i see two process's are using same port

Comment: Try to use the latest JDK 7. Your question seems to be a related to the http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7179799 which was fixed sometime after 7u5. Also there were [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204377/java-7-doesnt-throw-bindexception-when-binding-an-already-used-port-using-serve) questions already so yours could be a duplicate.

Comment: I am using openjdk version "1.7.0"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b146)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 21.0-b16, mixed mode). Issue exist with above version of open JDK as well?

Comment: The defect 7179799 is related to serverSocket same should fix the issue related to datagram socket as well?